# How do I make it to where the member's health drops each time?

Tags: python, postgresql, discord.py

I'm making a fighting game command, and want it to be where when you use the command, it takes away a random amount of health. They use it again, I want it to take away another random amount from the previous amount. So, say they have 100 health. I punch them. They lose 20 health, and they're left at 80 health. I use the command once more, and I want the 80 health to be subtracted from a random number

I should mention, what happens right now, is it just keeps taking away a random amount. So, if they had 80, and you used the command again, next time they might have 95

````
punch_damage = random.randint(1, 30)
    punch_damage1 = member_hp - punch_damage

    cursor.execute('SELECT user_id FROM fightgame WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s',
                   (user_id, guild_id))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result is None:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO fightgame(name, member_name, user_id, guild_id, attacker_hp, member_hp) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
                       (name, member_name, user_id, guild_id, attacker_hp, member_hp))
        conn.commit()

    if msg == 'punch':
        await ctx.send(
            f'{ctx.author.name} punched {member.mention} and took away {punch_damage} hp from them! They now have {punch_damage1} hp')
        cursor.execute('UPDATE fightgame SET member_hp = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s',
                       (punch_damage1, user_id, guild_id))
        conn.commit()
        cursor.execute('SELECT member_hp FROM fightgame WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s',
                       (user_id, guild_id))
        result = cursor.fetchone()
        if result[0] < 100:
            cursor.execute('UPDATE fightgame SET member_hp = %s WHERE user_id = %s AND guild_id = %s',
                           (punch_damage1, user_id, guild_id))
            conn.commit()```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
punch_damage1 = member_hp - punch_damage
member_hp = member_hp - punch_damage
# Takes away punch_damage from member_hp
```

Comment: That doesn't work, the same issue happens, it still just randomly assigns the member's health to a random amount

They start out with 100. You use the command, a random amount from 1 to 30 is taken away. What I want to happen is say you use it and the member now went from 100 to 80 health. I use it again, I want that 80 health to be taken away from another random amount

Comment: That should've fixed it. I don't know what's the error then.